# Animate Images Horizontally using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have mobile app build using jQuery Mobile. On intro screen I would like to add image which animate/move from left to right and right to left covering whole image. Below is the function which add animation effect. Unfortunately, when I change left property it adds white space on transition.

```
/*Moving image horizontally*/
    function moveRight() {
        $("#sample").animate({ left: "+=20" },8000, moveLeft)
    }

    function moveLeft() {
        $("#sample").animate({ left: "-=20" }, 8000, moveRight)
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        moveLeft();

    });
```

Also, transition is not smooth. I would like to add transition effect like LinkedIn app intro screen. Can any one share sample example which show animation with multiple images.

Thanks folks.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/J2RPq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find that a CSS transition runs more smoothly. Simply add `transition:left` property to the `#sample` style declaration and whenever you change the element's `left` property it will be animated.

```js
$(function(e) {
    $("#sample").css("left","100%");    
});
```

```css
#sample {
    left:0%;
    position: relative; 
    border:1px solid green; 
    background:yellow; 
    width: 100px; 
    height:100px;

    -webkit-transition: left 5s ease;
    -moz-transition: left 5s ease;
    -o-transition: left 5s ease;
    transition: left 5s ease; 
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sample">Sample</div>
```

Comment: It is only left transition. Is it possible to add image in div(width 80%) and animate whole image horizontally within div.

Answer (score 0):

i've found this:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a1/experiments/api-viewer/docs/animate/index.html

the main difference between your code and that one is the " symbol, sometimes you MUST use the simple one ('). (check the whole code, maybe there are another difference)

i've tried your code with just that change and it works property. (Chrome Version 40.0.2214.93 (64-bit))

Additionally, i recommend use graphic cores, it always works better for me. just like:

http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html

really simple, really beautiful ... hope this help : )